# How to stop playing audio with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I'm new to JQuery and JavaScript and I have this situation:

```
<button style="background-color: #dfe52d;border:4px solid #dfe52d" 
        class="button" type="button" >Play Me!</button>
<audio class="audio" src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

There are many buttons on my page, all with the same structure.  For each button I want play a different sound:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var isPlaying=false
        var audio = $(this).next().attr("src");
        var music = new Audio(audio);
        if(isPlaying) {music.pause()} 
        else{music.play();$(this).text("Stop Me")}
    });
});
```

When a button is clicked, the sound plays and the button text changes to "stop me".  How can I write the code to stop the audio? Also, if the user presses another button the current song must stop. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the isPlaying outside of the button click event and querying that so you know the state when you press the button. At the moment you set isPlaying to false every time you click.

```
var isPlaying=false
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").on("click", function(){
        var audio = $(this).next().attr("src");
        var music = new Audio(audio);
        if (!isPlaying) {
            // Not playing, let's play
            isPlaying = true;
            music.play();
            $(this).text("Stop Me")
        } else {
            // Stop the music
            isPlaying = true;
            music.pause();
            $(this).text("Play");
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cleanest solution.  Most of the functionality you're looking for is already built into the JavaScript for audio tags.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var audio = $(".audio")[0];
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            $(this).html("Stop me!");
        }  else {
            audio.pause();
            $(this).html("Play me!");
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi thanks all of you for the quick response.
unfortunately this two solution didnt work out, so i opted for this:

```
<button style="background-color: #dfe52d;border:4px solid #dfe52d;" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('audio1').play()" type="button" >Play Me!</button>
  <button style="background-color: #dfe52d;border:4px solid #dfe52d;" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('audio1').pause()" type="button" >Stop Me!</button>
  <button style="background-color: #dfe52d;border:4px solid #dfe52d;" class="button" onclick="document.getElementById('audio1').currentTime=0.0" type="button" >Restart Me!</button>
  <audio class="audio" id="audio1" src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Now works fine except one problem, i need a function to stop the current sound when another button is pressed. Is it a simple task in your opinion? Thank you